# Moving all zeros to the begining of array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to write a function which moves all numbers from begining of array to the end of it. order should not change.

for example i have this array:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0

i want to change it to:

0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

I already wrote a version of it but it can't keep the order. (array[] is original and a[] is sorted)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE_MAX 20

int main()
{
    int array[SIZE_MAX] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int a[SIZE_MAX];
    int i;
    int p = 0;

    for (i = SIZE_MAX-1; i >= 0; i--, p++)
    {
        a[i] = array[p];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE_MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about an array containing `{1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0}`?

Comment: Just a caution: initialising *part* of the array will set all the unspecified elements to `0`. The loops iterates over the whole array, not just the part you have initialised. So when you print the array, all those other `0` values will have been moved to the front too.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to loop through the array twice, first copying over the zeros, then the rest of the values:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE_MAX 10

int main()
{
    int array[SIZE_MAX] = {1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0};
    int a[SIZE_MAX];
    int i;
    int p = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE_MAX; ++i) {
        if (array[i] == 0) {
            a[p++] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE_MAX; ++i) {
        if (array[i] != 0) {
            a[p++] = array[i];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE_MAX; i++) {
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
}
```

I changed `SIZE_MAX` to 10, so that it matches the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 4):

The sentence *"I'm trying to write a function which moves all numbers from beginning of array to the end of it."* sounds like it should be done in place - and it turns out with this problem it is quite easy to do an in-place algorithm. Note that unlike other algorithms here, this just scans the array once, and writes the array once. Here I wrote it into a function:

```
void relocate_zeroes(size_t length, int *array) {
    int *target = array + length - 1;
    int *source = target;

    for (; source >= array; source--) {
        if (*source) {
            *target-- = *source;
        }
    }

    while (target >= array) {
        *target-- = 0;
    }
}
```

Basically we scan the source array once from end to beginning; and if we meet a non-zero integer, we relocate it just before the previous non-zero integer. When the whole array has been scanned, the area between the base (`array`) and `target` is filled with zeroes.

In the beginning both `target` and `source` point to the last value of the array; if the `*source` is not 0, we replace `*target` with `*source`; that is, if the last element is non-zero, we replace it by itself and decrease both `target` and `source` pointers; if the last element is 0, we don't copy it anywhere, only decrease the `source` pointer; continuing this way at the end we have copied all non-zero elements, and we can fill the remaining array elements with zeroes.

Given program:

```
#define SIZE_MAX  9

int main() {
    int array[SIZE_MAX] = {1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5};
    int i;

    relocate_zeroes(SIZE_MAX, array);

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE_MAX; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
}
```

The output will be

```
0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

---

If the 2-array version is *required*, then this is easy to modify for that too:

```
void relocate_zeroes(size_t length, int *source_array, int *target_array) {
    int *target = target_array + length - 1;
    int *source = source_array + length - 1;

    for (; source >= source_array; source--) {
        if (*source) {
            *target-- = *source;
        }
    }

    while (target >= target_array) {
        *target-- = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need all the `0` at the beginning and rest of the numbers in same order try this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE_MAX 9

int main()
{
    int array[SIZE_MAX] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int a[SIZE_MAX];
    int i;
    int temp[SIZE_MAX];
    int ind1=0,ind2=0;

    // separating all the 0's and store it at the beginning
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE_MAX; i++)
    {
        if(array[i]==0)
          a[ind1++]=0;
        else
          temp[ind2++]=array[i];
    }

    // storing rest of the numbers in order
    for (i = 0; i < ind2; i++)
    {
        a[ind1++]=temp[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE_MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
}
```

NOTE:
first i stored all the 0's in the result array and in the meantime all the non zero value are being stored in `temp` array.
later, i just merged the `temp` array to the result array.

Comment: i did. is there any problem to understand?

Answer (score 2):

Integer fullArray[] = { 1, 10, 20, 0, 59, 63, 0, 88, 0 };

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= fullArray.length - 1; i++) {

        if (fullArray[i] == 0 && i > 0) {

            int temp = fullArray[i - 1];
            if (temp != 0) {
                fullArray[i - 1] = 0;
                fullArray[i] = temp;
                
                i = -1;

            }

        }

    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(fullArray).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an in-place method using swap()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE_MAX 20

swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

moveZerosLeft(int length, int *array)
{
    int i = 0;
    int cur = length - 1;
    for( i = length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        if(array[i] != 0) 
        {
            swap(&array[i], &array[cur--]);
        }   
}

int main()
{
    int array[SIZE_MAX] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int i;
    int length = 9;

    moveZerosLeft(length, array);

    // display the result
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
}
```

We scan from the right of the array to the left. When we see a non-zero value, we swap it with a zero which we saw previously.

This method requires only 1 scan of the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Demo{

public static void moveZeros() {
    int[] num = {1, 0, 0 , 6, 7, 0};
    int temp=-1;
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length;i++)
    {
        if(num[i]!=0)
        {
           ++temp;
           if(num[temp] ==0){
               int val = num[i];
               num[i]=num[temp];
               num[temp]=val;
           }
           else
           {
               num[temp]=num[i];
           }
       }

    }
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Demo.moveZeros();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though question is old, I found a way to get the working solution in single pass with o(n) in Javascript

```
var a = [0,1,0,1,1,0];
var count = a.length;
for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
  if(a[i]!=0){
    j = i;
    while(j<count){
      if(a[j]==0){
        //swap the next element
        a[j] = a[i];
        a[i]=0;
        break;
      }
      j++;
    }
  }
}
console.log(a);
```